# Threads RootViewController exclude memory leaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

I have background thread, after some work I need to update my root viewcontroller with results.

```
+ (void)myBackgroundFunction {

    __weak MyAppRootViewController * view = ...;//Here I get my app root view controller
    view.needsUpdateFetch = YES;        

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [view reloadData];
    });
}
```

Should I use __weak to exclude memory leaks?
Is it right to change ivar variable(needsUpdateFetch) before block?
Or give me pls some links to read about.

Comment: Take a look at wwdc 2012 videos there is a nice video about blocks that explain how to use them correctly

Answer (score 0):

Whether you should use `__weak` or not it depends on where is this code written. You probably don't need it in this specific case, but it won't hurt to use it.